# Auto Update VBA Forms and Modules Online

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I am creating VBA Macros for Excel and recently have started using UserForms.

However, the dilemma is once the Excel File is deployed to the users, there comes a time that I need to update the code on the UserForms or Modules.

**What I would like to know is:** Is it possible to automatically update these UserForms or Modules by having Excel go online and download the updated UserForms and Modules like as patcher or something?

I got this idea from this [link](http://updatevb.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why don't you just release the Excel file as an addin, with version control? Users could download the addin as they needed (while this could be automated i think it is better to give the user "A new version is available")

Comment: Thank you brettdj.  I was afraid of this but it seems that this is the only way.

Upon browsing for the whole day, I have came upon this http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/updateanaddin.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204883/process-for-updating-excel-add-in) thread useful, it suggests ways to update an Excel add-in. I'd go down the route of getting the Excel file to update a separate small bootstrap file, that then handles any necessary update (suggestion by Robin Hammond on the thread).

Comment: Thanks ChrisN.  This actually a good suggestion to consider if one is to create an excel addin which in this case is the best route to go.

Comment: @SanchoAlmeda The only extra I can think you would need to do for an excel file is have the bootstrap move/copy the visible sheets to the new excel file before replacing it. I cant remember off the top of my head how formula references to other sheets in the original excel file would be handled when moving/copying sheets to the new file, but the last thing the bootstrap would do is replace the original file so it would either be referencing the location of it's self or  just it's self.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work, we solved this dilemma by storing the workbook on the network as a read-only file which is always used as the point of entry.

If the user wants to save it, they can do so on their own machine. If you want to update the file, you just switch out the current one, since it will not be locked (due to being read-only). Obviously, this approach only works if you have a shared network, but I think it's a rather simple to implement approach.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  This would also be a simple solution but as you said, would require to have a shared network.